# Finding Casimir operators for the Poincare group $ISO(1,2)$

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, lie-algebra, poincare-symmetry, invariants

I was asked to write the generators for translations and Lorentz-transforms in 1+2 dimensions and then to find the Casimir operators.

For the generators I can take the same ones as in 1+3 case

$$P_\mu = -i\partial_\mu$$

$$L_{\mu\nu} = (+i)(x_\mu\partial_\nu - x_\nu\partial_\mu)$$

as far as I can see, although the indices are now just 0,1,2, the commutation relations are the same as in the 1+3 case. It's like having the same relations for a limited number of them. But I don't know how to get the Casimir operators.

I know that for the 1+3 case they are $P^2$ and $W^2$. I have no problem declaring $P^2$ to be Casimir operator of the 1+2 case, but I have a problem generalizing $W^2$, since $W_\mu = \epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}J^{\nu\rho}P^\sigma$. I cant use this, there is no $\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$ (four indices) in 1+2 dimentions, but $J$ and $P$ still have the same number of indices as before (2 and 1, respectively), so I need a fourth index in order to write $W_\mu W^\mu$.

What can I do?

Comment: Actually I'm not, we did not dwelve into it in class (but we did get the question for HW). If it doesnt, then $J^2$ can characterize the quantum states alsone, as far as I understand. Does it mean that eigenstates of $P$ are also eigenstates of angular momentum?

Comment: Quadratic and Quartic Casimirs are e.g. listed on p. 3-4 in [arXiv:hep-th/0611263](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0611263).